# Construct a decision-tree classifier with binary splits at each node?

Tags: database, split, classification

Construct a decision-tree classifier with binary splits at each node, using tuples in relation **r (A, B, C)** shown below as training data; attribute C denotes the class. 
Show the final tree, and with each node show the best split for each attribute along with its information gain value.

**Training Data:**

`(1, 2, a), (2, 1, a), (2, 5, b), (3, 3, b), (3, 6, b), (4, 5, b), (5, 5, c), (6, 3, b), (6, 7, c)` ?

How to proceed?

Any link will be helpful?

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried so far? StackOverflow isn't here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you found what algorithm (i.e. ID3) do you want to use to build your decision tree? To predict the class, you need to train your decision tree based on observations about data (i.e. features). This [lilnk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) explains the decision tree learning.